# Why is the rep shown as user reputation in proposal different from rep shown in flair

Tags: support, reputation, area-51, flair

I notices this two launched proposals. [Home Improvement](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/170/home-improvement) and [Food and Cooking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1288/food-and-cooking.)

I looked at the top beta users and found something strange. The reputation shown as the user reputation is different from the reputation shown on the flair

On Home Improvement

[image]

and On Food and Cooking

[image]

To clarify all doubts I clicked on some of the profiles and found out that the reputation shown in the flair is the correct one.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's presumably showing their reputation earned while the site was in beta, as it's the list of top beta users. Naturally their current reputation, as depicted by the flair image, has a strong chance of being higher now that those sites have been out of beta for many years.

Comment: Presumably, but far from obviously.  As with many things related to Area51 this could be made more clear!